# Qweb templates on odoo client side rendering versus server side rendering

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have a question about the qweb templates of Odoo. Why can we create a template inside the `static` folder and have it rendered on the client by javascript and why can we create a template that will be rendered on the server side and returned by a controller?

What is the difference, what can I do on the one that I cannot on the other and what are the different **use cases**?

Example of frontend rendering:

Take a look at `addons/web/static/lib/qweb/qweb2.js`. This file has the `render` function which is used to render templates created on the `static` folder. For an example of its usage see `addons/account/static/src/js/account_reconciliation_widgets.js`. There are multiple `Qweb.render(template_name)` statements there. So from what I can understand templates inside static are accesible to the client in their initial format and rather the web client is responsible for the rendering

Comment: Not trying to be difficult here, but I do not believe the xml is rendered `server side`. The xml is parsed and processed server side (ie. `t-foreach` is interpreted and replaced with the appropriate content) and sent to the client for rendering.

Comment: Have not had time to run much in the way of tests. However, as for qweb templates which are processed on the client I think they are almost exclusively used for javascript widget xml. I have not seen them used elsewhere. I think the main goal would likely have been to support client side dynamic content. Backbone js uses xml templates extensively and Backbone heavily influenced Odoo's js framework.

Comment: So I guess in a way Odoo has two almost parallel MVC paradigms one that is handled by the controllers loading xml views (although still qweb) and another which seems to be processed client side using a qweb template structure similar to backbone.

Comment: The crazy part is that they seem to intermix from time to time. I wish someone else would comment. I would hate to think I know what I am talking about, or worse, someone else think I know what I am talking about.

Comment: @phillipstack Please take a look at my edited question for an example of frontend rendering/parsing of a template located in the static folder.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. You also see the same structure in Flask and Django (that is, making resources available from the static folder). Although the difference is that Flask and Django (to my knowledge) do not serve xml from the static directory.

Comment: However this kind of falls back to my previous statement that there is this dichotomous MVC paradigm occurring in Odoo.

Comment: As for the benefits or use cases. I really think this falls into security and or the dynamic nature of the page presented on the client.

Comment: There are times that you obviously do not want to need a constant back and forth from the client to the server in order to provide updates to the UI. In this case I guess client side templates are a better fit such as changing the state or clicking a checkbox to display / not display content (or modify display). But should not really require a request to the server.

Comment: However I for one would really like to hear other people's thoughts on what the appropriate use cases are.

Comment: Hope you do not mind, I have posted the question on Odoo's community forum and linked back here. Hopefully more meaningful discussion ensues.